# Why WinDbg does not reconnect after target computer reboot?

Tags: driver, windbg, hyper-v, wdk, kmdf

I was [Setting Up KDNET Network Kernel Debugging Automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection-automatically#restarting-the-target-pc) to [provision a computer for driver deployment and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1#provision-the-target-computer) in order to [Write a Hello World Windows Driver (KMDF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) and after rebooting my target computer, WinDbg is still waiting to reconnect...

Both my host and target computers have Win10 (x64)
I am using Hyper-V, my host computer is the server (local) and my target computer is one of its workstation.

I tried to restart my target computer using `shutdown -r -t 0` and followed the procedure to start a WinDbg session with the executable (*WinDbg.exe, not the command line option*). I also tried to turn off my firewall, but it does not helped.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully disabling firewalls on both target and host computers have solved the issue.